# How to use jenkins version number plugin in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, version, jenkins-pipeline

Trying this step in Jenkinsfile with "version number plugin" installed:

```
    stage("Build") {
        echo "Building..."
        TAG = ${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED, "yyyyMMdd"}-develop-${BUILDS_TODAY}
        sh "docker build -t $IMAGE:$TAG ."
    }
```

And getting this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 15: unexpected token: BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED @ line 15, column 15.
           TAG=${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED, "yyyy-MM-dd"}-develop-${BUILDS_TODAY}
                 ^
1 error
```

What is correct way to use this plugin in Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use it as a step.

```
tag = VersionNumber (versionNumberString: '${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED, "yyyyMMdd"}-develop-${BUILDS_TODAY}')
```

Take a look at https://your_jenkins_url.com/pipeline-syntax/ and check all the options for the VersionNumber step in the snipped generator.

Answer (score 0):

in Jenkinsfile.. try this

```
env.BN = VersionNumber([
        versionNumberString :'${BUILD_MONTH}.${BUILDS_TODAY}.${BUILD_NUMBER}', 
        projectStartDate : '2017-02-09', 
        versionPrefix : 'v1.'
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

In stage use the script block to run for version numbering

```
stage("Build") {
    script {
        TAG = VersionNumber(versionNumberString: '${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED, "yyyyMMdd"}-develop-${BUILDS_TODAY}')
        echo "Building..."
        sh "docker build -t $IMAGE:$TAG ."
     }
  }
```