# How to use jenkins version number plugin in pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am using version number jenkin plugin in Jenkins ver. 2.107.2.  below pipeline code is not working. any help to fix this issue?

**pipeline code**

```
pipeline {

            agent any
            stages {
                stage('Pre-Build') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'echo Building Docker' 
def tag = VersionNumber (versionNumberString: '${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED, "yyyyMMdd"}-develop-${BUILDS_TODAY}')
}

                        } 

                }

}
```

**Error:**

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: Expected a step @ line 8, column 1.
   def  tag = VersionNumber (versionNumberString: '${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED, "yyyyMMdd"}-develop-${BUILDS_TODAY}')
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:325)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

this link [How to use jenkins version number plugin in Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471602/how-to-use-jenkins-version-number-plugin-in-jenkinsfile) has answer but not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the declarative Pipeline, which has some restrictions regarding the commands which can be run inside a stage.

Take a look at the [syntax guide for declarative pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline).

You can either use the [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) or declare the variable in an `environment` block:

```
environment {
        tag = VersionNumber(versionNumberString: '${BUILD_DATE_FORMATTED,"yyyyMMdd"}-develop-${BUILDS_TODAY}');
        }
```

and later use it as `$tag` in your pipeline.